Android: setImageBitmap with bitmap of QR I'm generating in runtime is not working
I have this code:
private fun initQRCode() {
    binding?.let {
        val bindingRequired = it
        val helloWorld = QRCode.ofRoundedSquares()
            .withColor(R.color.colorPrimaryMid)
            .withSize(90)
            .build("Hello world!")

        val pngBytes = helloWorld.render()
        val byteArr = pngBytes.getBytes()
        val bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArr, 0, byteArr.size)

        bindingRequired.idIVQrcode.setImageBitmap(bmp)
    }
}

I tried to put breakpoints on bmp and see if it generates and it does.
but on screen it stays as follow:

the xml object is:
<!--We are using this image
    view to display our QR code-->
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/idIVQrcode"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        android:contentDescription="QR Code"
        android:src="@color/quantum_grey"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />


It looks like an issue in the QR code library. Make sure use are using the latest version.
